# Images disappeared from backend but still in SSh

Tags: magento2, product-images, backend, export, ssh

I do have an issue with product images, In the backend there are no images

Export from Magento shows images are assigned correctly and the images are available in SSH.

The issue is not all the products and I don't have a backup to upload it again especially they are already in the SSH

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a full reindex:

```
1: bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If the issue is still present, do `Flush Cache` also `Flush Image Cache` for the images in Backend and run:

```
2: bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```